# how to minimize window to maximize window using shortcut key in window application using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hotkeys

how to  minimize window to maximize window using  shortcut key in window application using c# ?

Answer (score 2):

Set Form Propertie "KeyPreview" = true.

Then use this code:

```
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.B)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }
    }
```

Comment: its work when u can see form but when minimized then what happend??i wont have sictuation that minimize to maximized window form?

Comment: see my comment in the other answer

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your accept rate, I will give you the steps:

- Add a [KeyDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265634/keydown-recognizing-multiple-keys) event handler on to the form you want minimized/maximized.
- Add code to check for the [key combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265634/keydown-recognizing-multiple-keys) you want
- Use [`Form.WindowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate.aspx) to set the state you require.

As a sidenote, please start accepting answers. You can do it by clicking the "tick" next to an answer that helped you solve your problem.

Comment: its work when u can see form but when minimized then what happend??i wont have sictuation that minimize to maximized window form?

Comment: then you must register a Globale Windows HotKey. See here:
http://dotnet-snippets.de/dns/globale-hotkeys-tastenkombinationen-SID356.aspx

Comment: i m tell u that when i have minimized application then how to maximized application...?

Answer (score 0):

thanxs man its working and if we can change our state with this key follow this code..

```
 if (e.Key == Key.F11)
            {
                if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
                {
                    this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Werewolve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318272/werewolve) mentioned correct [link](http://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/globale-hotkeys-tastenkombinationen/356)!

When application is minimized it will not receive any keyboard input. Otherwise applications would not who was the keyboard target.

If you want your application to receive signal when specific keys combination where pressed you should register this combination by calling RegisterHotKey Windows API function.

Your form showing/maximising action could be invoked by this signal/