# KeyEventArgs.KeyData, KeyEventArgs.KeyCode and KeyEventArgs.KeyValue

Tags: c#, .net, keycode, key-value, keyeventargs

I have question about the `KeyEventArgs`'s `KeyCode` and `KeyData` and `KeyValue`.
`KeyCode` and `Keydata` are Keys type, but I don't know what the difference between them is. For `KeyValue`, I don't know what it is -- it has an `int` type, does it return the `char` value of the pressed key?

I don't have much experience with Key events; any explanation of how they function and how to use them would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`KeyCode` contains data for the key that produced the `KeyUp` or `KeyDown` event. `KeyData` contains the combination of that key together with CTRL, SHIFT or ALT if any of those were pressed.

Example:

- Press (and hold) CTRL. `KeyDown` will be raised, `KeyCode` will be `Keys.ControlKey`, `KeyData` will be `Keys.ControlKey | Keys.Control`.
- While still holding CTRL pressed, press SHIFT. `KeyDown` will be raised, `KeyCode` will be `Keys.ShiftKey` and `KeyData` will be `Keys.ShifKey | Keys.Shift | Keys.Control`.

Note that `KeyData` and `KeyCode` can contain any value in the [`Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx) enumeration (such as `Keys.A`, `Keys.NumPad4` or `Keys.Up`). Note that when one of the modifier keys are pressed, it is represented by two values in `KeyData` (one for they key and one for the modifier value). The modifiers are also available through the [`Modifiers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.modifiers.aspx) property.

`KeyValue` will return a numerical value representing the key, essentially an integer representing the value found in `KeyCode`.

Comment: So key data can only be CTRL ALT or SHIFT keys?And what about KeyValue?

Comment: So when i press ahift KeyCode can only be Keys.ShiftKey and it will never be Keys.Shif?
Oh and is Keys enumerated from 0 to MaxKeys or is it enumerated like in the ASCI table for example A - 65

Comment: @Bosak: exactly. Note though that pressing 'A' will always give 65, regardless of whether you are typing an uppercase or lowercase letter. Remember that the values represent the keys, not the letters they produce.

Comment: Yes if i need to check the letters ill need to check the modiffers or key data for a shift key :) Thanks alot you helped me!