# Why pressing Ctrl+M is not working?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want my application to respond to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> it will do something:

```
if (e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.M 
    && e.KeyCode == System.Windows.Forms.Keys.RControlKey)
```

I tried to click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (I tried both left and right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys) and it stops at a breakpoint on the `if` but never goes in. Why not?

Comment: Look at the statement. Can `KeyCode` every be equal to two different values at once?

Comment: Replace e.KeyCode == whatever with e.KeyCode & whatever == whatever

Comment: There is a very similar post on SO [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265634/keydown-recognizing-multiple-keys)

Comment: `Ctrl+M` has `ASCII` code decimal `13` (= code of `M` minus 64). You get the same code for "Carriage Return" or `Enter`. Enums `System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Enter` and `System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Return` both have value `13`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're doing doesn't make sense:

`e.KeyCode` is an enum value, which can only hold one value at a time, an enum value cannot be both `Keys.M` and `Keys.RControl` at the same time(1).

Windows handles Control (and other special keys) as modifiers, the correct way is like so:

```
if(e.KeyCode == Keys.M && e.Control) {
```

or

```
if(e.Keycode == Keys.M && (e.Modifiers & Keys.RControl) == Keys.RControl) {
```

(1)(not counting `Flags`, and I know `Keys` is marked as `Flags`, but i'm trying to keep things simple)