# C# Ctrl+F doesn't work sometimes

Tags: c#, winforms, keyup, keystroke

I have a winforms application where in I have a `textbox` inside a form. I need to set focus to the `textbox` whenever I press 'Ctrl+F'. I have the following code in `keyup` event.

```
        private void frm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {     
            // Handle 'Ctrl + F' to Find    
            if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.F))
                SetFocus();
        }
```

Problem I have here is that sometimes, even though the focus is on form and I try 'Ctrl+F' the condition doesn't run. I know, as soon as I press 'Ctrl' the event gets fired even before I would have pressed key 'F'. Eventually it works, when I press both the keys at the very same time. So to the user it might look like the screen is unresponsive to the keys sometimes.

How can I overcome this situation?

Comment: shouldn't you handle `KeyDown` instead?

Comment: Why not handle KeyDown and check there if Control is down when F is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the KeyUp event and checking if the event contains both keys. This will only happen when you *release* both keys at the same time.

Change it to the KeyDown event instead, and [check whether <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> was pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265634/keydown-recognizing-multiple-keys) at the moment <kbd>F</kbd> was pressed:

```
if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.F)
{
    // ...
}
```