# How to get fire if text selected and its replace

Tags: c#, icsharpcode

in c#  how to trigger if text is selected
example here is if copy event happen getting triggered with below code

```
private void Hook_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Control)
            {
                 // code executed here 
            }

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Control)
            {
                 // code executed here 
            }
        }
```

as same need if text Selected or `ctrl+shift+rightarrow` event happen need to fire and execute code like fire paste event

Comment: Hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/1265653/9760311